# How to apply conditional logic using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have customized some coding in my site

There is a select field which has options:
1) singaporean
2) singapore PR
3) others

once user select others, a text field will appear below for the user to key in any nationality user want to key in

The problem here is that I have managed to get the text field to appear but after press "save settings" button, the text field disappears but the data is saved.

```html
<li class="jobsearch-column-6">
  <label><?php esc_html_e('Nationality', 'wp-jobsearch') ?></label>
  <div class="jobsearch-profile-select">
    <label for="NationalitySelect">
      <select name="nationality" id="NationalitySelect" class="selectize-select" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Nationality', 'wp-jobsearch') ?>">
    </label>
    <option <?php echo ($nationality=='Singaporean' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>value="Singaporean">
      <?php esc_html_e('Singaporean', 'wp-jobsearch') ?>
    </option>
    <option <?php echo ($nationality=='Singaporean PR' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?> value="Singaporean PR">
      <?php  esc_html_e('Singaporean PR', 'wp-jobsearch') ?>
    </option>
    <option <?php echo ($nationality=='Others' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>value="Others">
      <?php esc_html_e('Others', 'wp-jobsearch') ?>
    </option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="others_nationality" class="form-control" id="OthersNationalityInput" value="<?php echo ($others_nationality) ?>" />
  </div>
</li>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).on('change', '#NationalitySelect', function() {
    var nationalothers = $('#OthersNationalityInput');
    if (this.value == 'Others') {
      nationalothers.show();
    } else {
      nationalothers.hide();
    }
  });
</script>
```

I want the text field to remain shown after the button "save settings" is pressed.

Comment: save settings button means form submission? Check weather your page is refreshing on the button click.

Comment: `<select>` is wrapped inside `label` tag, but `options` and `</select>` is outside, that's invalid html

Comment: Upon submitting the pages refreshes. Your jQuery function is only checking for changes made to the select list. By adding the same checking function when your page is ready should do it.  
$(function() { // check and set here; });

Comment: @PonsPurushothaman, yes ,its the form submission and the page refresh after the button is click.

Comment: @barbsan, ok so whats the solution to the invalid html. I am quite a newbie here in coding but have a bit of knowledge from reading up and testing on my own. appreciate if you can give me a solution to this

Comment: @Kes sorry but can u guide me on how to do this.

Comment: @AhmadAbdillahHaron either `<label><select><option></option><!--more options--></select></label>` or `<label></label><select><option></option><!--more options--></select>`

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the page get refreshed so it disappears. Try to add the textbox by PHP on form submit

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
  echo"<input type='text' val='value from database'/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming after you submit then the page refreshed and the values in your form are maintained, you can modify your jQuery to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function() {
    var nationalothers = $('#OthersNationalityInput');
    if (this.value == 'Others') {
      nationalothers.show();
    } else {
      nationalothers.hide();
    }
  });

  jQuery(document).on('change', '#NationalitySelect', function() {
    var nationalothers = $('#OthersNationalityInput');
    if (this.value == 'Others') {
      nationalothers.show();
    } else {
      nationalothers.hide();
    }
  });
</script>
```

But of course you should optimize the code above by keeping things DRY.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by changing this line

```
<input type="text" style="display:none;" name="others_nationality" class="form-control" id="OthersNationalityInput" value="<?php echo ($others_nationality) ?>" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" style="display:<?php echo ($nationality=='Others' ? 'block' : 'none'); ?>" name="others_nationality" class="form-control" id="OthersNationalityInput" value="<?php echo ($others_nationality) ?>" />
```